# How to package Firefox and Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am new to Firefox and Chrome extension development.

I have downloaded and tested helloworld sample extension in both FF and Chrome in development mode.

Followed the following steps to work properly in FF and chrome,

- In FF

  1. Extracted the sample extension, and added one file in `/mozilla/firefox/dev_user/helloworld@mozilla.doslash.org` and given extracted folder path.
  2. My FF version is 12.0 and I changed the`<em:maxVersion>` to 12.0.* in `install.rdf` file.
  3. Restarted  FF and tested, it worked fine.
- In Chrome:

  1. Extracted the sample extension
  2. Choose Tools > Extensions
  3. Checked Developer mode
  4. Click the Load unpacked extension button
  5. Dialog appears and selected extracted sample extension folder path
  6. Extension is added and works perfectly.

Now I would like to know how to package these extensions? I mean on clicking the package that extension should install directly in the browser instead of following the above steps.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally not a good idea to ask four questions at once. Let's try to answer all your questions:

> How do I package a Firefox extension?

You follow the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension#Package) (a Firefox XPI package is simply a ZIP archive).

> How do I package a Chrome extension?

You follow the [official documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html).

> How do I make sure a Firefox extension can be installed from a website?

That question is already answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522800/how-to-achieve-automatic-installation-of-firefox-addon-on-hosted-on-own-websit).

> How do I make sure a Chrome extension can be installed from a website?

You cannot. Current Chrome versions make it very complicated to install extensions from third-party sites. Your best bet is to upload your extension to the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) (as a ZIP archive of extension files, not a proper package - Chrome Web Store creates the package for you). Once the extension is in the Chrome Web Store you can use [inline installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) to simplify installation from the website associated with your extension.

Comment: RE "You cannot". That is not true, [the user can re-enable the feature via the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049366/re-enabling-extension-installs/12071194#12071194). However, you're right in the sense that the average Joe will not be able to easily install the extension, because they don't know how to change the default setting.

Comment: @RobW: As I said, "current Chrome versions make it very complicated". This doesn't mean that the user cannot install an extension if he really wants to (there are actually several tricks) - but not too many will, this no longer is a viable extension distribution mechanism. The OP asked about installation without unpacking the extension, the available approaches aren't significantly less complicated however.