# Exporting/Packaging Firefox add-on to web extension xpi

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm recently looking into Firefox web extension development and I have no prior extension development skills therefore, accept my apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

I have developed an extension to manipulate certain elements in a certain domain. It works great in `Firefox about:debugging` environment. I've only used jQuery and Javascript to manipulate my settings on DOM. No SDK or XUL has been used.
`storage.local` and `browser tabs` API used to store & transfer my data.

My questions are how to export this source code to test amongst few friends to verify functionality before signed by `AMO` and my approach in here is right or wrong.

<kbd>manifest.json</kbd>

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.domain.com/*"
            ], 
            "run_at": "document_start", 
            "js": [
                "jquery.js", 
                "flat_ui_min.js", 
                "application.js"
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "name": "Extension name goes here", 
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/extension-icon-48.png"
    }, 
    "description": "Sample description goes here", 
    "homepage_url": "URL to the extension info", 
    "version": "1.2", 
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "icons/browser-icon-32.png"
        }, 
        "browser_style": true, 
        "default_title": "Extension short name", 
        "default_popup": "popup/layout.html"
    }, 
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", 
        "storage", 
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

<kbd>install.rdf</kbd>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">

    <em:id>name@domain.org</em:id>

    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <em:name>Extension name</em:name>

    <em:version>1.2</em:version>

    <em:description>Extension description</em:description>

    <em:creator>Creator's name</em:creator>

    <em:homepageURL>Extension homepage</em:homepageURL>

    <em:optionsType>1</em:optionsType>

    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>Some random string</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>46.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>57.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

<kbd>Directory Structure</kbd>

```
Extension Folder
    └─── install.rdf
    └─── manifest.json
    └─── jquery.js
    └─── application.js
    └─── flat_ui_min.js
    └─── popup/
            └─── css/
                  └─── bootstrap.min.css
                  └─── flat-ui.min.css
                  └─── style.css
            └─── fonts/
                  └─── glyphicons/
                  └─── lato/
            └─── layout.html
    └─── icons/
            └─── browser-icon-32.png
            └─── browser-icon-48.png
```

Appreciate your thoughts in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: A WebExtension should not have an *install.rdf*. Why do you believe you should have one?

Comment: As i said, picked up couple of things from here and there. I couldn't find a complete tutorial related to my coding style though. I suppose i could remove that and zip the files again. When trying to install that zip file or xpi file in `about:addons` it gives me `this addon could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt` error.

Comment: As you've mentioned, you have not yet had it signed by Mozilla, so you should be using `about:debugging`, not `about:addons`. Please see: [Firefox extension .xpi file structure: description, contents, creation, and installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043045) for info on packaging add-ons and [Add-on "appears to be corrupt" when trying to install my add-on's .xpi file in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856780) specifically for the most common cause of the "appears to be corrupt". However, we really *can't* answer with anything but guesses/general info without actually having acce

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply. The reason i'm trying to install this as it is now is to handout `.xpi` to few friends and get their opinion. I've allowed Firefox's unsigned extension add-on exception. I'll look at your docs and see how it goes. Meanwhile shall I submit what i have now to `AMO` and see what happens?

Comment: You should get it to the point that you can install it as a temporary add-on from `about:debugging` using the *.xpi* file prior to submitting it. There is no other way to get it signed, other than to submit it to AMO. The only ways to allow an unsigned add-on to be installed from about:addons is to be running Nightly or Developer Edition, or to completely disable the add-on signing requirement (which can be done on a per Firefox install basis; see: [How can I disable signature checking for Firefox add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403531))

Comment: Found a small mistake from my end. I will update the comment once i resolve that. :)

Comment: Is the *manifest.json* in the root directory of the *.xpi*? In other words, there should be no subdirectory between the top of the *.xpi* file and the *manifest.json*. You can have subdirectories under that (as you do), but the *xpi* root should contain your *manifest.json*. Without the actual *.xpi* file, we *can't* do anything other than guess here.

Comment: Sorry yes, 7zip made a folder inside the .xpi file and i've removed that. Now having a trouble when installing the extension follows by `There was an error during installation: Add-on Author@domain.com is not compatible with application version.` This is just in under `<em:id>Author@domain.com</em:id>` Full install manifest is posted under my question. :)

Comment: As I said, WebExtensions don't use *install.rdf* files.

Comment: Thank you sir, You're amazing. removing the rdf file made the extension working under `about:debugging` so shall i submit this to `AMO` and get it signed? +1 for your help :)

Comment: Submitting to AMO is up to you. It's a required step if you're wanting to distribute it. You've past the most important part of what you need prior to submission: a functional extension package.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO user [makyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) has given his thoughts and ideas of making this extension to test upto my standards. Posting those here as an answer is to make it as a guide to other beginner developers to overcome my question.

**Following changes were done:**

new settings for <kbd>manifest.json</kbd>

```
{
    "description": "brief intro about the extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.2",
    "name": "Extension name",
    "homepage_url": "Developer or extension website",
    "icons": {
        "32": "icons/browser-icon-32.png",
        "48": "icons/browser-icon-48.png",
        "96": "icons/browser-icon-96.png",
        "128": "icons/browser-icon-128.png"
    },    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "flat_ui_min.js",
                "application.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://*.somedomain.com/*",
                "*://*.somedomain.org/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Extension browser title",
        "default_popup": "popup/layout.html",
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "icons/browser-icon-32.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

I removed <kbd>install.rdf</kbd> as web extension don't need one. When it comes to packing the extension, Follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856780/1173209). More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16419291/1173209).

After that simply change file extension from *filename.zip* to *filename.xpi* to distribute.

Happy coding everyone.!